# My images in react will not load onto the page. How do I load a local image file?

Tags: reactjs, image, import

Trying to add an image from my assets folder, but can't seem to reach back that far?

`<img class='fade-in' src={'.../assets/images/logos/SWSLogoNOBG.png'} />`

Can I not reach back that far with the dots? I can use two and it works, but is three too much?

I've also tried

`import SWSLogo from '.../assets/images/logos/SWSLogoNOBG.png';`

then done

`<img class='fade-in' src={SWSLogo}/>`

but that also doesn't work?

I feel super dumb and could use some help cause this one little problem has taken me two days of trying and I've made zero progress.

---

Edit:

I've made it work, but only by moving my image file into the same folder as my Home.js file.

Can react not reach files outside of the immediate directory? Why is this so stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to go multiple nested folders up then for every folder you need another '../'

for example, if you have

```
 1. src
    2. folder
       3. folder
          index.js
    app.js
```

you would need to do '../../app.js'

if you are using a hard coded path, use quotes:

```js
    <img
      alt="dolphin"
      src="../../images/dolphin.jpg"
      ariaLabel="dolphin"

    />
```

if you are pulling from say a JSON you would do something like:

```js
const animals = {
  dolphin: {
    image: '../../images/dolphin.jpg',
    facts: ['Dolphins have been shown to give distinct names to each other!', 'Dolphins are known to display their own culture!', 'Dolphins have two stomachs!']
  },
  lobster: {
    image: '../../images/lobster.jpg',
    facts: ['Lobsters taste with their legs!', 'Lobsters chew with their stomachs!', 'Lobsters can live as long as 100 years.']
  },
  starfish: {
    image: '../../images/starfish.jpg',
    facts: ['Starfish can have up to 40 arms!', 'Starfish have no brain and no blood!', 'Starfish can regenerate their own arms!']
  }
};
const images = [];
for (const animal in animals) {
  images.push (
    <img
      alt={animal}
      src={animals[animal].image}
      ariaLabel={animal}
    />
  )
};
const allImages = 
(
  <div className='animals'>
  {images}
  </div>
)
ReactDOM.render(allImages , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: That was it, Thank you! I needed to use the ../../ in order to go deeper into the files

Comment: Hey, I'm glad it worked! If you could spare the time to mark this as the correct answer so others can hopefully find this answer more easily in the future that would be great.